# Python: wait for user input, and if no input after 10 minutes, continue with program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried:

```
from time import sleep
while sleep(3): 
    input("Press enter to continue.")
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I want the program to await user input, but if there's no user input after 10 minutes, continue with the program anyway.

This is with python 3.

Comment: you're going to need a thread, probably.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Why does the code not work?**

`time.sleep` returns nothing; the value of the `time.sleep(..)` become `None`; `while` loop body is not executed.

**How to solve it**

If you're on Unix, you can use [`select.select`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html).

```
import select
import sys

print('Press enter to continue.', end='', flush=True)
r, w, x = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 600)
```

Otherwise, you should use thread.

**Windows specific solution** that use [`msvcrt`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html):

```
import msvcrt
import time

t0 = time.time()
while time.time() - t0 < 600:
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        if msvcrt.getch() == '\r': # not '\n'
            break
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple way using an alarm. When the time expires, the lambda function is called, which would raise a `ZeroDivisionError`.

```
from signal import signal, alarm, SIGALRM

signal(SIGALRM, lambda x, y: 1/0)
try:
    alarm(600)
    input("Press enter to continue.")
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("timed out")
```

Comment: [`signal.alarm`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.alarm) is only available in Unix.

Comment: Sadly some people are still using non-[POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compliant OS

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do it is this:

```
from time import sleep
print("I'm executing")
try:
    print("Wake up Ctrl-C!")
    sleep(600)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("I woke up!")
else:
    print("I'm executing again.")
```

Not the greatest of answers and it definitely feels like an abuse of exceptions, but it works.

Comment: It's not an abuse, it's just not related to the question. Where is the user input here?