# Python: loop stops when user input quit, continues even without an input

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to continue the program without waiting for a user input? 
I want the loop to continue after 2 seconds even without user input, and break if the user type quit. This code is not working, because I need to manually hit enter every time to be able to continue the loop.

```
while True:
    answer = input("please enter quit to stop the program")
    time.sleep(2)  # wait for 2 seconds for the possible user input "quit"
    if answer == "quit":
        break
    ... other code
```

operation system: windows 7, python 3.6

I have read: [Python: wait for user input, and if no input after 10 minutes, continue with program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508353/python-wait-for-user-input-and-if-no-input-after-10-minutes-continue-with-pro)
and: [raw_input and timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471461/raw-input-and-timeout/3911560#3911560).
I tried the answers for windows and none of them worked. I didn't completely understand them either. 
Could you please comment on the major steps in the code? Thank  you so much!

Comment: I don't get why you use `time.sleep` here. `input` waits until the user hits ENTER.

Comment: I believe this answers it?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508353/python-wait-for-user-input-and-if-no-input-after-10-minutes-continue-with-pro

Comment: Because I tried to wait 2 seconds for the user to input, even if he doesn't input anything, after 2 seconds, the program continue. I tried all the methods in the other two threads, none of them worked..

Comment: `r, w, x = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 600)`  # where 600 is timeout in seconds, check: select.select for details