# Reaction Time Game - How would I show some message/error for when enter is pressed before stated 'GO!!'?

Tags: python

How would I show some message/error for when enter is pressed before stated 'GO!!'?,
as currently when enter is pressed before stated, 'diff' or 'reaction time' is 0.0002 or next to 0?

```
import random
import time

print("Reaction Time\nPress Enter when stated 'GO' ")

time.sleep(random.randint(1, 4))
then = time.time()
input("GO!! ")
now = time.time()

diff = now-then
print("\nYou took " + str(diff) + " long")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this, is to create a separate thread with the standard `threading` library. You create a thread, that waits for an input and if it is received, then a variable is modified in the main thread.
The flow goes like:

1. Start a thread that waits for input
2. Wait the time
3. Check if variable in main thread has been modified (pressed too early)
4. start the timer and print `GO!`
5. End timer when the variable in main thread is modified (aka input is provided)

This has the downside, that the message `Pressed too early.` is only printed when the wait timer is up.

Here is your modified code:

```
import random
import time
import threading

print("Reaction Time\nPress Enter when stated 'GO' ")

def get_input(l):
    """This function runs in a new thread and waits for the user to press enter"""
    data = input()
    l.append(data)
    return
inp = []
input_thread = threading.Thread(target=get_input,args=(inp,))
input_thread.start()
print("Wait...")
time.sleep(random.randint(1, 4))
if inp: #Check if list is still empty
    print("Pressed too early.")
    exit(0)
start = time.time()
print("GO!")
while not inp: #While the list is still empty, run the timer
    pass
end = time.time()
diff = end - start
print("\nYou took " + str(diff) + " long")
```

There is dicussion of a similar problem/tools to solve such problems here: [Python: wait for user input, and if no input after 10 minutes, continue with program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19508353/python-wait-for-user-input-and-if-no-input-after-10-minutes-continue-with-pro) and [Key Listeners in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python)